# How can i login with single role if user have multiple role assigned in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, acl

I have a use case that a user having multiple role but want to login user with a single role at a time and give the rights of respective role. 
For example a user have employee,manager & finance manager role and each role has its own permissions/rights. So, now i want the system ask for role selection when user trying to login in the system and on the basis of selection it would authenticate .

**Laravel 5.4**

**Zizaco/entrust 1.3.x**

TIA.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple guard function for different user roles. you can edit that in config/auth.php

During sign in you can use a drop down menu. Based on that input you can define different guard in your controller. Your code can be something like the following;

```
if (request('role')=='admin')
   if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)){
       // your code to login
   }

else if (request('role')=='user')
   if(Auth::guard('user')->attempt($credentials)){
       // your code to login
   }
```

For more information on authentication you can view the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)

Comment: Hi nabil thanks for your response, basically i want a user should be login  with a single role and all associated permissions will be available of that role or may be you can say it role authentication

Comment: i am using zizaco/entrust somehow it is restricting this kind of functionality.